# MySQL result as variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have for example a var.php, that connect to a database, and read some data from there:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "$".$row["name"]. " = " . $row["value"]. ";<br>";
        }
```

and the result looks like:

```
$VAR1 = 3.00000;
$VAR2 = 5.00000;
$VAR3 = 8.00000;
$VAR4 = 9.00000;
```

How can i embed this php (using echo or include or require) in another php, and will it work like variables? ( Sorry for my poor english :( )

Comment: you could try to create a class, and put this in a function and use the function in an instance of the class.

Comment: sessions or cookies.

Comment: Why not to use arrays?

Comment: why you are not using an array?

Comment: try [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) like this on top of another php page `$vars = (include 'var.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at variable variables (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

For your example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
      $$row["name"] = $row["value"];
}
```